# Mysql average value every minute refer to unix timestamp

Tags: mysql, average, unix-timestamp

I logging my temperature every 1-3 seconds with unix timestamp, I wish like get row of data return by average every 1 minute period and last for 24 hour.

my logger table look like this:

```
unixtime    temp
1350899052  25.37
1350899054  25.44
1350899057  25.44
1350899059  25.44
1350899062  25.44
1350899064  25.44
1350899069  25.44
1350899071  25.44
```

and i wish like it  return as

```
unixtime    temp
1350899052  25.37 -- average value of 1 minute range both unixtime and temp 
1350899054  25.44
1350899057  25.44
```

please advise how is mySQL command should i do ? thank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work:

`SELECT   ROUND(unixtime/(60)) AS minute, avg(temp)
FROM     table where unixtime >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) GROUP BY ROUND(unixtime/(60));`

Show date in normal format:

`SELECT from_unixtime(floor(unixtime/(60))*60) AS minute, avg(temp) FROM test where unixtime >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) GROUP BY floor(unixtime/(60))`

outputs:

```
minute  avg(temp)
2012-10-24 08:02:00 37.5
2012-10-24 08:03:00 45
```

Comment: Yes, because it shows minutes from 1970. What should your output look like?
2012-10-12 00:00:01 25,777
2012-10-12 00:00:02 28,999
?

Comment: i got return as munite : 22517598 26.64000075204032 not unix time average as i expect, but close to how could i get return as unix time in average period, thank for help

Comment: could you explain GROUP BY ROUND(unixtime/(60)); i don't understand how it work. thank again.

Answer (score 0):

```
 1. 1 min

select * from logger_table where unixtime> timestamp(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)) group by temp

 2. 24 hrs
select * from logger_table where unixtime> timestamp(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)) group by temp;
```

Comment: there may be no data within this 1 min