# Get the average of values in every specific epoch ranges in unix timestamp which returns -1 in specific condition in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, aggregate-functions, unix-timestamp

I have a MySQL table which has some records as follows:

```
unix_timestamp           value

1001                     2
1003                     3
1012                     1
1025                     5
1040                     0
1101                     3
1105                     4
1130                     0
...
```

I want to compute the average for every 10 epochs to see the following results:

```
unix_timestamp_range         avg_value

1001-1010                    2.5
1011-1020                    1
1021-1030                    5
1031-1040                    0
1041-1050                   -1
1051-1060                   -1
1061-1070                   -1
1071-1080                   -1
1081-1090                   -1
1091-1100                   -1
1101-1110                    3.5
1111-1120                   -1
1121-1130                    0
...
```

I saw some similar answers like [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53593388/mysql-how-to-get-avg-of-values-into-specific-range) and [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13043705/mysql-average-value-every-minute-refer-to-unix-timestamp) and [enter link description here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/98043/query-calculating-avg-per-minute-group-by-timestamp) but these answers are not a solution for my specific question. How can I get the above results?

Comment: Did you see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: The most difficult part is to compute the intervals, once you get that, you use group by

Comment: @Strawberry My table fields are too many, so I don't mentioned the table creation statement.

Comment: @Cristian what about -1 value when a range has no value? Is it easy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use a calendar table.  Consider this approach:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(CAST(cal.ts AS CHAR(50)), '-', CAST(cal.ts + 9 AS CHAR(50))) AS unix_timestamp_range,
    CASE WHEN COUNT(t.value) > 0 THEN AVG(t.value) ELSE -1 END AS avg_value
FROM
(
    SELECT 1001 AS ts UNION ALL
    SELECT 1011 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1021 UNION ALL
    ...
) cal
LEFT JOIN yourTable t
    ON t.unix_timestamp BETWEEN cal.ts AND cal.ts + 9
GROUP BY
    cal.ts
ORDER BY
    cal.ts;
```

In practice, if you have the need to do this sort of query often, instead of the inline subquery labelled as `cal` above, you might want to have a full dedicated table representing all timestamp ranges.

Comment: Thanks, but my ranges number are not static and can be changed when my max unix_timestamp is large.

Comment: Also this query does not produce -1 value

Comment: You need to maintain a table containing all the ranges which might appear.  And it does return -1 for ranges having no data.

Comment: Why when I add a `where` on `t` (`where t.node in (3,4,6,8)`) clause before `Group by`, the ranges with -1 value disappears?

Comment: What is the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: Move that logic to the `ON` clause of the left join.  That is, use this: `LEFT JOIN yourTable t ON t.unix_timestamp BETWEEN cal.ts AND cal.ts + 9 AND t.node in (3,4,6,8)`

Comment: Thank you very much. That was the solution.